# Select Query With Distinct on One Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This is My Select Query:

```
SELECT 
[T1].[Id], [T2].[Id] , [T3].[Id] 
FROM  [T1]
INNER JOIN [T2] On [T1].[Id] = [T2].[T1Id]
INNER JOIN [T3] On [T2].[Id] = [T3].[T2Id]
```

The result is :

```
1  1  1
1  2  2
1  2  3
2  3  4
2  3  5
3  4  1
```

But what I need is distinct on `[T1].[Id]` Something like this:

```
1  1  1
2  3  4
3  4  1
```

This is not important the first record of Id returned , So the result could be:

```
1  2  2
2  3  4
3  4  1
```

but it is important that the columns of each record have a logical relations, So I can't Use `Min` or `Max` functions. The first solution I think is Insert values to a temp table and remove duplicates.

But I think that must be a better way? something in select query.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Which of the 1-rows do you want? `1 1 1`, `1 2 2` or `1 2 3`? And more importantly, why? (ie. don't say "the first", say things like "the one with the highest third column, or something that can be programmatically checked)

Comment: As Lasse said, in DB-terms it is ALWAYS important which data is returned. Even if you don't care, you need to know why. Basically if it doesn't matter whether it returns 1,1,1 or 1,2,3, then why would it matter if it returns the second and third value at all, since you can't extract reliable data from it anyway? Unless you're just checking whether T1 is referenced by T2 and T3, which is also required information that can affect the specs here. :)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I get what you said, but assume I need just a relation between T1,T2,T3 and this is important not which relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
 Select 
 ID1,ID2,ID3
 from 
 (
   SELECT 
        [T1].[Id], [T2].[Id] , [T3].[Id] ,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by [T1].[ID] order by [T1].[ID])
   FROM  [T1]
   INNER JOIN [T2] On [T1].[Id] = [T2].[T1Id]
   INNER JOIN [T3] On [T2].[Id] = [T3].[T2Id]
)a
where a.rn = 1
```

Comment: That's wonderful, but I think there is a mistake in get rown umber. partition and order by must be  `[T1].[Id]`

Answer (score 1):

```
;with a as
(
SELECT 
[T1].[Id] ID1, [T2].[Id] ID2, [T3].[Id] ID3, 
  row_number() over (partition by [T1].[Id] order by newid()) rn
FROM  [T1]
INNER JOIN [T2] On [T1].[Id] = [T2].[T1Id]
INNER JOIN [T3] On [T2].[Id] = [T3].[T2Id]
)
SELECT ID1, ID2, ID3
FROM a
WHERE rn = 1
```